# Webflux, How to intercept a request and add a new header

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Using `Webflux` filter, I am trying to intercept the requests and check if the request is coming from certain `URI` then add a new `Authorization` header

The filter code is simple and straightforward

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        return chain.filter(Optional.of(exchange)
                .filter(serverWebExchange -> serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath().endsWith("/callback"))
                .map(serverWebExchange -> addNewHeader(serverWebExchange))
                .orElse(exchange));
    }

    private ServerWebExchange addNewHeader(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {

        String authHeader=serverWebExchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().get("state").get(0);

        if (authHeader == null) {
            throw new BadRequestException("State not complete (access_token missing) for //callback");
        }

        try {
            serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().setBearerAuth(authHeader);
        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return serverWebExchange;
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.set(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:99)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.setBearerAuth(HttpHeaders.java:774)
```

It seems the header map is read only.How can i overcome this issue and add the new Header ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can mutate the `ServerWebExchange` and its `ServerHttpRequest` with their `mutate()` methods which returns a 'Builder' for each of them.

Example Java:

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationFilter implements WebFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest mutatedRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + authHeader).build();
        ServerWebExchange mutatedExchange = exchange.mutate().request(mutatedRequest).build();
        return chain.filter(mutatedExchange);
    }
}
```

Example Kotlin:

```
@Component
class AuthorizationFilter : WebFilter {
    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val mutatedRequest = exchange.request.mutate().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer $authHeader").build()
        val mutatedExchange = exchange.mutate().request(mutatedRequest).build()
        return chain.filter(mutatedExchange)
    }
}
```

Comment: The weird thing is.. we don't need to call `mutate` for modifying response. Just `exchange.response.headers.add("x-test-response", "test-value")`  will works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! I used it to add header to responses but it worked only for non-error responses. I resolved this problem by adding highest order for the filter bean:
`@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`

Answer (score 2):

The problems caused because you add a new header in the `map` operator of the chain, in this case webflux finilized `serverWebExchange` and it is immutable. You just need to add a header before calling `chain.filter(...)`.

Comment: I am doing the same way. But sometimes, I got mentioned error. Not sure what I am missing. out 10-15 times, I use to get once or twice this error

Comment: add example of your code and error to verify

Comment: I had a logical error. Pretty new in Reactive programming. But Your answer makes sense to me. Got the answer to my error.